# Imaginary number/exponent rules misconception

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I must be doing something wrong in the following question and would appreciate clarification:

Given that $i^2$= -1, and that k is a positive integer, what is the value of $i^{4k+2}$?

My answer:

$i^{4k+2}$ = $i^{4k}$+$i^2$

$i^{4^{k}}$+ $i^2$

$i^2$=-1, $i^4$=1

$1^k$=1 + $i^2$ = 0

The answer should be -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong 
$$i^{4k+2}=i^{4k}+i^2$$
This is right
$$i^{4k+2}=i^{4k}\cdot i^2=-i^{4k}=-(i^4)^k=-1$$

Comment: Thank you, I should have caught that.